# Can Sweave read R files?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am new to Sweave/Tex and would like to keep my R code out of the Sweave file as much as possible.  Ideally, I would like to reference my R files within Sweave's .Rnw file and then have Sweave read it directly.

An example might be something like this:

```
    \begin{document}
    \title{Project}
    \author{Author}
    \date {\today}

    <<>>=
    **Reference to file: projectcode.R**
    @

    \begin{figure}[H]
    <<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE,png=TRUE,pdf=FALSE,eps=FALSE>>=
    ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
    @
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a "yes" because the snippet between `<<>>=` and `@` is for R code, so you can use `source()`.

But just because you can does not mean you should.  There are templating solutions as e.g. the [brew](http://cran.r-project.org/package=brew) package, or you could try the newest kid on the block, the [knitr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=knitr) package.

Comment: and in particular, knitr features [code externalization](http://yihui.github.com/knitr/demo/externalization/)

Comment: So it sounds like I'm not the only one who wanted to put R code outside of the Rnw document :) (thanks for the link, baptiste)

Comment: Yihui - thanks for building knitr.  It looks like a great alternative.  I'm going to try it.